# I'm using an IEEEtran class but I'm having trouble aligning the third author's name

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ieeetran, author

I'm having trouble aligning the third author block. Please help. I've already tried similar answers here but they didn't help much.

[image]

```
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author1}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Engineering and Computer Science} \\
\textit{BRAC University}\\
Dhaka, Bangladesh \\
email1@gmail.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Engineering and Computer Science} \\
\textit{BRAC University}\\
Dhaka, Bangladesh \\
email2@gmail.com}
\and\and\and

\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 3}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Engineering and Computer Science} \\
\textit{BRAC University}\\
Dhaka, Bangladesh \\
email3@gmail.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 4}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{School of Engineering and Computer Science} \\
\textit{BRAC University}\\
Dhaka, Bangladesh \\
email4@gmail.com}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please help us to help you.: provide complete small document which reproduce your problem, not just code snippet!

Comment: On page 5 of the manual it says "If there are more than three authors and/or the text is too wide to fit across the page, use an alternate long format:" which puts the affiliations into footnotes.